# Saving image from Html5 canvas to phone storage

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, html5-canvas

Using Phonegap (javascript), I'm trying to shrink an image the user selects from his gallery and copy it to another folder structure.

I've been trying everything I can think of and am running out of ideas. I know there are a couple of similar questions out there, but none work for me.

**Method 1**

Trying to take an image from a canvas object and store it on the phone's local storage using PhoneGap. This works in that I get an image saved, but it's corrupted. I've tried a bunch of different ways. I've tried to use `Uint8Array`, `atob` conversion, etc. See some of the code below.

**Method 2**

Trying to use the copyTo function. However, I'm having two issues with this. 
1) I don't want the full size image (takes up too much storage space)
2) The object I'm copying is always 0 bytes, for some reason.

Here's some of the main code, please help.

```
function gotFileEntry(fe, file, type) {
alert("gotFileEntry: " + file.size);
// copy file
fe.file(function (f) { alert(f.size); }, function (e) { alert(e.code); });
fe.copyTo(dirImg, "copy.jpg", function(f) {alert("successful copy: " + f.fullPath);}, null);

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function (event) {
    // shrink image
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = reader.result;
    img.onload = function () {
        var newWidth = $(".page").width() * .8;
        var newHeight = img.height / img.width * newWidth;
        canvas.width = newWidth;
        canvas.height = newHeight;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);

        // use setTimeout to allow the canvas to finish drawing
        setTimeout(function () {

            var shrunkImg = canvasToData(type, canvas); //canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

            // save image data to the phone storage
            var imgData64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/data:image\/png;base64,/, ''); //canvas.toDataURL("image/png");//.replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");                
            setTimeout(function () {
                dirImg.getFile("test.png", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (f) { getWin(imgData64, f); }, getFail);
                //dirImg.getFile(file.name, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (f) { getWin(imgData, f); }, getFail);
            }, 0);

            setTimeout(function () {
                // returns data as Uint8Array array
                var data = Base64Binary.decode(imgData64);
                dirImg.getFile("test2.png", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (f) { getWin(data, f); }, getFail);
                //dirImg.getFile(file.name, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (f) { getWin(imgData, f); }, getFail);
            }, 0);
            //var uintArray = Base64Binary.decode(data);
            //fe.createWriter(gotFileWriter, function (error) { alert("CreateWriter failed: " + error.code); });

            // Save the image path to the database
            editCardView.card().UpdateImagePath(fe.fullPath);

            // Display the image
            $("#imgDisplay").attr({ "src": shrunkImg });
        }, 0)

    }
};
reader.onerror = function (event) {
    errorHandler2(event.target.error.code);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function getWin(data, f) { f.createWriter(function(w) { writeWin(data, w); }, writeFail); };
function writeWin(data, writer) {

    writer.write(data);
    //writer.write(atob(data64)); 
};
```

Comment: Do you have idea about plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin its work for me. to save canvas base64 to image on sdcard

```
<head>
    <title>
        Hello World
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, 
    width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    //Base64code  indicate about our canvas base64.
     var Base64code = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIAAAACACAYAAADDPmHLAAAgAElEQVR42sS9d5xl11Xn+937hJtj5djVObdaauVkWZIt29gYbDlhjHkwJANDmmGY8ObBzGMew4c3MDAwQ3jYfgYeOQx4HL";

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady() {
            cordova.exec(function(winParam) {
                console.log(winParam)
            }, function(error) {}, "Base64toImagePlugin", "base64Data", [Base64code]);
        }
    </script>
</head>
 <body>
</body>
```

Java code of Plugin class name :   Base64toImagePlugin.java

```
    package com.inic.base64toimage.Plugin;

    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Base64;
    import android.util.Log;

    import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
    import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;

    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;

    /**
     * Created by ind652 on 08/10/13.
     */
    public class Base64toImagePlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

        @Override
        public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {


            if (action.equals("base64Data")) {


                Log.i("BASE64DATA", "FastCanvas queueing set background color " + args.getString(0));

                byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(args.getString(0).getBytes(), 0);
                Bitmap b=  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
                storeImage(b,"amitd.png");
                return true;

            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }

        private boolean storeImage(Bitmap imageData, String filename) {
            //get path to external storage (SD card)
            String iconsStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myAppDir/amit/";
            File sdIconStorageDir = new File(iconsStoragePath);

            //create storage directories, if they don't exist
            sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();

            try {
                String filePath = sdIconStorageDir.toString() + filename;
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);

                //choose another format if PNG doesn't suit you
                imageData.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);

                bos.flush();
                bos.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //    Log.i("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            } catch (IOException e) {
          //      Log.i("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

config.xml:

com.inic.base64toimage.Plugin is package name where you can create plugin class

```
<feature name="Base64toImagePlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.inic.base64toimage.Plugin.Base64toImagePlugin" />
</feature>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, I guess I should just use a plugin. I just thought I was so close without using a plugin, just that the file format is wrong, for some reason.